# Python - How to read xml from HDFS?

Tags: python, xml, hdfs

I'm working with PySpark, I want to read xml from HDFS using `xml.etree` librairie.
This is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
dom = ElementTree.parse('hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/response.xml')
```

But I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/response.xml'
```

Is there any way to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not "How to read XML from HDFS?" but "How to read *any* file from HDFS?" - And searching for this leads to results like this: https://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: But I would work with ElementTree I should do some search in XML file, for the other types like CSV it works fine

Comment: data = sc.readFile('hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/response.xml')

Comment: @SudevAmbadi readFile dosen't exist in SparkContext

Comment: Sorry sc.textFile("hdfs path"); this will help you read the data into a rdd. If you have XML in many lines, you will have merge them before passing it as a input to ElementTree.parse()

Comment: How can I merge the XML to work as an input of ElementTree?

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas is possible using pyarrow do connect hdfs, after so you it achieves import xml by way read functions of pandas, where this data will be transformed into a pandas dataframe. Example:

```
import sys,os
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import fs

hdfs_config = {
     "host" : "hdfs://namenode",
     "port" : 9000,
     "user" : "root"
}

fs = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem(hdfs_config['host'], hdfs_config['port'],user=hdfs_config['user'])

path = "hdfs://namenode:9000/user/userExample/dirExample/fileExample.xml"

df = pd.read_xml(path)
```

PS: The "read_xml" is a function to pandas version 1.3 or higher, but can be replaced by other read functions.